# How to position the main Container if i have a Topbar and and a sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of learning HTML and CSS and am currently trying to recreate the Spotify Web Player. So far I have rebuilt the topbar and sidebar and am trying to work on the main view. I'm trying to do this using a div, which is supposed to divide into different divs.

The main div is called "start-preview-container" and it should be placed just below the topbar and next to the sidebar. When I create this div, using the dev tools I see that the "start-preview-container" also extends under the sidebar and topbar and I don't want that. I want this div to start exactly where I marked the lines. I can't find my mistake and hope you can help me.

[Acutally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDILx.png)

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-sidebar.css">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "styles-topbar.css">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "startpreview.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = sidebar-flexbox-container>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <div class = "spotify-logo-container">
        <img class = "spotify-logo" src="spotify-logo.png" >
      </div>
      <div class = "options-container">
        <div class = "options-logo-container">
          <img class = "logo" src="home-button.png">
          <p class = "logo-label">Start</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "options-logo-container">
          <img class = "logo" src="search-logo-sidebar.png">
          <p class = "logo-label">Suchen</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "options-logo-container">
          <img class = "logo" src="bib-logo.png">
          <p class = "logo-label">Bibliothek</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="options-container">
        <div class = "options-logo-container">
          <img class = "logo" src="playlist-logo.png">
          <p class = "logo-label">Playlist erstellen</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "options-logo-container">
          <img class = "logo" src="lieblingssong-logo.png">
          <p class = "logo-label">Lieblingssongs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="seperator">
      </div>
      <div class = "options-container">
        <p class = "logo-label">Deine Top-Songs 2021</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Trance Classic</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Lowkey-Tech</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Club Beats</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Emotionaler Techno</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Dein Mix der Woche</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Techno Bunker</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Electro Rising</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Techno State</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Deine Top-Songs 2020</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Rock</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Pop</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Dark Metal</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Metal Core</p>
        <p class = "logo-label">Hardtekk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "topbar-flexbox-container">
    <div class = "left-section">
      <div class = "back-button-container">
        <img class = "back-button" src = "back-button.PNG">
      </div>
      <div class = "further-button-container">
        <img class = "further-button" src = "further-button.PNG">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "middle-section">
      <input type="search" id="suche" placeholder="Was möchtest du hören?">
      <div class = "search-logo-container">
        <img class = "search-logo-search" src = "search-logo.PNG">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right-section">
      <div class = "profile-picture-container">
        <img class = "profile-picture" src="ErwinBause.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class = "name-container">
        <p class = "name">Erwin Bause</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "drop-down-menu-container">
        <i class = "arrow-down"></i>
        <div onclick = toggleDropDown() class = "drop-down-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class = "start-preview-container">
    <div class = "title-container">
      <div class = "title-one">
        <p class = "title-label">Basierend auf deinem Hörverlauf</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "show-more-container">
        <p class = "show-more-label">Alle Anzeigen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS-Code-Sidebar:

```
.sidebar-container{
  background-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.spotify-logo-container{
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
}

.spotify-logo{
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
}

.logo{
  width: 30px;
  height: 27px;
}

.logo-label{
  color:rgb(179, 179, 179);
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.options-container{
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:15px
}

.options-logo-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;  
  cursor: pointer;
}

.seperator {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

CSS-Code TopBar:

```
body{
  height: 3000px;
}
.topbar-flexbox-container{
  display:flex;
  position: fixed;
  left:250px;
  right: 0px;
  top:0px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.left-section{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-button-container{
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back-button{
  width: 35px;
  height: 33px;
}

.further-button{
  width: 35px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.further-button-container{
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.middle-section{
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

#suche{
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-right: 39px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  height: 40px;
}

#suche::placeholder{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  padding-left:-50px;
}

.search-logo-container{
  position: absolute;
  top:7px;
  left:7px;
}

.search-logo-search{
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;

}

.right-section{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:1100px;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-picture{
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.name-container{
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.name{
  color:white;
  margin:0;
}

.drop-down-menu-container{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;


}

.arrow-down{
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:0;
}

.drop-down-content{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

CSS-Code-Main-Container:

```
.start-preview-container{
  display:flex;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left:242px;
}

.title-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  margin-left:200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  align-items: center;

}

.title-label{
  color: rgb(3, 216, 3);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;

  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:60px;
}

.show-more-container{
  display:flex;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.show-more-label{
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:14px;

  cursor: pointer;

  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top:60px;
}

.playlist-container-top{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I tried to work with margin-top and and margin-left. As well as with position:relative and then using the attributes left and top. But when I scroll, the topbar and sidebar are hidden. Here I also tried to work with the z-index, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could use the `display: grid` for this and remove all fixed positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem that you have is caused by the positions of topbar and sidebar, called fixed, when you write this position on the container, it takes the container out of document flow(just like position:absolute), so I think good way to help with your problem will be to add empty element just below your `position:fixed` elements and make them same width and height as your sidebar and topbar, or better one would be to use margins(`margin-top` should be same as height of topbar, `margin-left` should be same as width of sidebar)

```
.start-preview-container{
{
  display: flex;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 65px;


}
```

and remove all unneccesarry margins on child tags of `.start-preview-container`